# Convert a list to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion, converters

I have a list that includes:

```
list = [(Year, 'make', 'model')]
```

Using Python, is it possible to convert it to a dict, where the year is the key:

```
dict = {Year : {'Make' : [models]}}
```

example :

```
{
2013:{
'Scion' : ['FR-S,' 'tC'],
'Subaru' : ['BRZ'],
'Toyota' : ['Land Cruiser', 'Venza'],
}
2012:{
'Scion' : ['FR-S,' 'tC'],
'Subaru' : ['BRZ'],
'Toyota' : ['Venza'],

}
```

}

Comment: Yes, I believe it is possible. Do you have a specific question regarding the process? If not, you can always come back if you are stuck.

Comment: can you give us the input?

Comment: @FelixKling yes I am stuck I have been trying since yesterday to come up with a solution to this problem, but I can't, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Then please post the code you have so far and let us know where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> values = [('Year', 'make', 'model')]
>>> result = {}
>>> for lst in values:
...     leaf = result
...     for path in lst[:-2]:
...        leaf = leaf.setdefault(path, {})
...     leaf.setdefault(lst[-2], list()).append(lst[-1])
...
>>> result
{'Year': {'make': ['model']}}
```

Comment: thank you, this works just the way I wanted, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the correct answer was already posted, but this is what I came up with:

```
list = [(2012, 'make', 'model'),(2012, 'make', 'model2'),(2013, 'make', 'model')]

D = dict()
for li in list:
    if li[0] not in D:
        D[li[0]] = { li[1]: [li[2]] }
    elif li[1] not in D[li[0]]:
        D[li[0]][li[1]] = li[2]
    else:
        D[li[0]][li[1]].append(li[2])

print (D)
```

Answer (score 3):

The only trick here is to get the initialisation of the `defaultdict` correct. The rest of the code then becomes very simple.

```
from collections import defaultdict

D = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for year, make, model in the_list:
        D[year][make].append(model)

print(D)
```

Answer (score 2):

Lookup [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
L = [('Year', 'make', 'model')]
answer = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(list))
for year, make, model in L:
  answer[year][make].append(model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, it's a dict inside a dict. You want your dict to be

```
cardict = {year1:{make1:[model1,model2...],...},...}
```

where your the dots are the other years, makes and models. I'm not sure how you want to input it, whether you want an automatic input system or parser or what, but the question asks it possible to have a list inside dict inside a dict, and it is.

If you have more specific questions, post your code and you'll get help.

Edit: I think the onboard python dictionary should be enough; I don't really think you need to import any other dictionaries.